# Feynman tricks to reproduce Onsager's solution of the 2D Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, ising-model

I found the following quote in this paper:

Wilson, Kenneth G. "The renormalization group and critical phenomena." Reviews of Modern Physics 55.3 (1983): 583.

> Later, Jon Mathews explained some of Feynman's tricks for reproducing
>   the solution for the two-dimensional Ising model. I didn't follow what
>   Jon was saying ...

Is there somewhere one can read about what Feynman tricks this quote is referring to?

Comment: My memory is that [Feynman's book on Statistical Mechanics](https://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Mechanics-Lectures-Frontiers-Physics/dp/0201360764) had a chapter on the Ising model and Onsager's solution, so I would guess in there

Comment: @BySymmetry Yes! I have copy with me and I see a derivation of the Onsager's solution in section 5.4. You can post an answer if you like. I'll wait a bit to accept it in case someone else finds another reference.